# strip html, inline styling and new line, tab chars from json in python

Tags: python-3.x, html

i have a external json file which has some inline coding, html tags, \n and \t chars i want to remove all those things and want to keep only strings without breaking json format so far i have tried this and have seen many solutions but nothing worked. Really appreciate for your time. Here is my code

I am using python 3.x.x

```
import json, re
from html.parser import HTMLParser

def remove_html_tags(data):
    p = re.compile(r'<.*?>')
    return p.sub('', data)

with open('project-closedtasks-avgdaysopen.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    data = json.dumps(data, indent=4)
print(data)
```

please note this is the file which i am getting in (importing from same folder) And i want same output but no html tags, no inline styling, no \n or other things only string.

```
[
    {
        "idrfi" : 36809,
        "fkproject" : 33235,
        "subject" : "M2 - Flashing Clarifications",
        "description" : "<ol style=\"margin-left:0.375in\">\n\t<li><span style=\"font-family:calibri; font-size:11pt\">Refer to detail 5/A650 attached. Can the pre-finished metal panel be swapped for pre-finished metal flashing? This will allow the full assembly to be installed by the mechanical HVAC trade vs requiring the cladding trade to return for penthouse work. </span></li>\n</ol>\n",
        "response" : null
    },
    {
        "idrfi" : 36808,
        "fkproject" : 33139,
        "subject" : "M1 - Flashing Clarifications",
        "description" : "<ol style=\"margin-left:0.2in\">\n\t<li><span style=\"font-family:calibri; font-size:11pt\">Refer to detail 6/A612 attached. Clarify location of flashing on detail.</span></li>\n\t<li><span style=\"font-family:calibri; font-size:11pt\">Refer to details 2,4/A614 attached. Clarify location of flashing on detail. </span></li>\n\t<li><span style=\"font-family:calibri; font-size:11pt\">Refer to detail 3/A616 attached. Clarify location of flashing on detail.</span></li>\n\t<li><span style=\"font-family:calibri; font-size:11pt\">Refer to detail 5/A650 attached. Can the pre-finished metal panel be swapped for pre-finished metal flashing? This will allow the full assembly to be installed by the mechanical HVAC trade vs requiring the cladding trade to return for penthouse work. </span></li>\n</ol>\n",
        "response" : null
    }
]
```

I found the function but i don't know how to implement it

```
def remove_html_tags(data):
    p = re.compile(r'<.*?>')
    return p.sub('', data)
```

**edited**
after this implementation the &nbsp, \n, \t and other things are not removing i want only string no tags no styling nothing

```
import json, re
from html.parser import HTMLParser

def remove_html_tags(data):
    p = re.compile(r'<.*?>')
    return p.sub('', data)

with open('project-closedtasks-avgdaysopen.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    data = json.dumps(data, indent=4)
    removed_tags = remove_html_tags(data)
print(removed_tags)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just call that function you have written

```
import json, re
from html.parser import HTMLParser

def remove_html_tags(data):
    p = re.compile(r'<.*?>')
    return p.sub('', data)

with open('project-closedtasks-avgdaysopen.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
    data = json.dumps(data, indent=4)
    removed_tags = remove_html_tags(data)
print(removed_tags)
```

I checked it , it's working fine.

Comment: after last line ? i should write this ?

Comment: &nbsp, \n, \t is not removing

Comment: you have to write regex for it or use replace function removed_tags.replace('&nbsp','')